# Why does my function in Beanshell don't work? | JMeter

Tags: function, jmeter, beanshell

I use a Beanshell-Sampler to write a file in Jmeter.
And I tried to use some functions like:

```
status = ${__property(status)};
```

or

```
${__time(EEE\, d MMM yyyy)};
```

it just worked with the Webdriversampler but not in Beanshell. 
Is it not possible to use a function in Beanshell or is just an import missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inline functions in Beanshell script, but you need to use quotation marks like:

```
String status = "${__property(status)}";
String date = "${__time(EEE\, d MMM yyyy)}";
```

By the way, is isn't recommended to use Beanshell scripting so if you have possibility to amend JMeter installation(s) it's better to consider [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)  and Groovy as a language instead.

If you decide to switch to JSR223 and Groovy - you should stop referring variables and functions as ${...} and start doing it from Groovy code like:

Accessing property value:

```
String status = props.get("status");
```

Getting current date:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy");
String date = sdf.format(new Date());
```

See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) guide for Beanshell vs Groovy benchmark, details on installation of Groovy scripting engine support in Jmeter and scripting best practices.